# Set LastModifiedDate in Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am preparing the `testSetup()` and I need to set the `LastModifiedDate` of the record one month earlier. Is that possible somehow?

> Field is not writeable: Contact.LastModifiedDate

Answer (score 1):

To create testdata with lastModifiedDate in the past follow the below link

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332070&type=1&mode=1

OR

Step 1- Create CSV File for your sobject

**name    createdDate            lastmodifiedDate**

Test1   2000-01-01T00:00:00Z    2001-01-01T00:00:00Z

Test2   2000-01-02T00:00:00Z    2001-01-02T00:00:00Z

Step 2 - save as Static Resource (named here as recordsWithLastModDateInPast)

Step 3 - Code test method

```
@istest
private static void testLastModDateInPast () {

    TestObj__c[] recordList = test.loadData(TestObj__c.sObjectType,'recordsWithLastModDateInPast');
    system.debug(loggingLevel.INFO,recordList);
}
```

Comment: Hey Chetan, can you add some context and code snippet explaining? It has often seen that links die and the answer becomes irrelevant then/

Comment: Hi Pranay, I have added code snippet for reference.